# Double to Const Char*

Tags: c++, char, double

How can I convert a double into a const char, and then convert it back into a double?

I'm wanting to convert the double to a string, to write it to a file via fputs, and then when I read the file, it will need to be converted back into a double.

I'm using Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition.

Comment: If you are using C++ do you really want to use char and fputs?

Comment: Better to use binary files, instead of text files and store the double "as-is". Then read it "as-is". Ensure that "structure" of file doesn't change.

Comment: I'd like to support what Ajay said: it is much more effective to use binary files and store the doubles as doubles rather than converting them to a decimal representation (if only because this is likely to introce rounding errors!), only to be able to write it to a text file in string form.

Comment: Another thing: don't say "convert `double` to const `char*`", you never want to do this. What you actually mean is "convert `double` to array of char and give me a pointer to this array". Or simply "convert `double` to `string`".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to write the `double` values to file, you can simply write it, *without* converting them into `const char*`. Converting them into `const char*` is overkill.

Just use [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) as:

```
 std::ofstream file("output.txt")'

 double d = 1.989089;

 file << d ; // d goes to the file!

 file.close(); //done!
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't know this was possible, LOL. I've only been working with C++ for a few days.

Answer (score 8):

Since you added C++ to your tags, I suggest you use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
#include <sstream>

stringstream ss;
ss << myDouble;
const char* str = ss.str().c_str();
ss >> myOtherDouble;
```

Comment: You should add that after any call to a non-const member function the pointer should not be treated as valid.

Answer (score 3):

You can use these functions to convert to and from:

```
template <class T>
bool convertFromStr(string &str, T *var) {
  istringstream ss(str);
  return (ss >> *var);
}

template <class T>
string convertToStr(T *var) {
  ostringstream ss;
  ss << *var;
  return ss.str();
}
```

Example:

```
double d = 1.234567;
string str = convertToStr<double>(&d);
cout << str << endl;
double d2;
convertFromStr<double>(str, &d2);
cout << d2 << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this funcition :

```
const char* ConvertDoubleToString(double value){
    std::stringstream ss ;
    ss << value;
    const char* str = ss.str().c_str();
    return str;
}
```